# Internal Inspection other than X-ray

Tags: x-rays

I'm looking for the contactless methods to collect the information of the body construction especially skeletal structure to calculate in the computer model . 
Are there physical methods to inspect internal side of the body other than X-ray and no any exposure of radiation ? For example, echo , MRI and so on .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you consider "radiation".  [Ultrasound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound) doesn't involve radition.  [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) involves radiowaves, which are electro-magnetic radiation (but not ionizing radiation).  [Proton Imaging](http://www.physics.niu.edu/nicadd/research/medical/CTScanner2012.pdf) and [Neutron Imaging](http://mnrc.ucdavis.edu/tomography.html) do not directly involve electro-magnetic radiation, but the term [ionizing radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation) is usually defined to include particles that cause ionization regardless of whether the particles are photons (electro-magnetic radiation).